# Backround-Image Repeat inside Table: To send via Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, background-image

Struggling to get this emailer to work when sending to a PC in Outlook, the background-image is inside a table inside the header and footer. Can anyone suggest a better code that will make this work.

Thanks.

http://www.bwiprojects.com/email/april-2014/april-newsletter.html

Comment: Background image isn't supported in Outlook 2007/10/13 http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Outlook only supports background images in two ways:

1. In the `<body>` tag
2. Using VML

In your case, as it is not a full email background, you will need to use VML. I suggest you check out [backgrounds.cm](http://backgrounds.cm/)